# A and B and C and D (comma)

Tags: commas

There is a sentence:

> I am grateful to Mr. White for A and B[,] and to Mr. Black for C and D.

Should I put a comma before "and to Mr. Black" or not?

Comment: I might want _extra_ commas if the actual replacements for A, B etc are lengthy. As your coded sentence stands, is it (1) unclear, (2) poorly balanced (3) shrieking 'poor style' in either format? And (4): Will the average reader need a breather after "I am grateful to Mr. White for A and B"?

Comment: Well, actually I wrote just a scheme which is very common in my language (Russian), so I sometimes need to do something with it when trying to translate. The situation is: you have 'A and B', you also have 'C and D', then you join them together with another 'and' so that (A and B) and (C and D). In Russian we have a strict rule - no commas here. Is there anything similar in English?

Comment: Punctuation is usually seen here as a servant rather than a dictator. Obviously, a free-for-all would be counter-productive, but there is probably much more freedom of choice here. Check in decent literature and on web articles addressing comma usages.

Answer (score 3):

A series of two separated by *and* generally does not need a comma. So

> I am grateful to Mr. White and Mr. Black.

or

> I am grateful to Mr. White and to Mr. Black.

However, where the two elements of a series have an internal *and* (or where they are very complex), a comma to indicate the separate elements of the series is considered helpful.

> "I am grateful to Mr. White for A and B, and to Mr. Black for C and D."

Answer (score 1):

I would say not, because *and* is not joining two clauses. The points Edwin raises were not part of your question, but they are still worth considering, particularly if the letters stand for longer sequences of words.